# How should I upgrade Ryder's Life support?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I've been grinding myself in Mass Effect Andromeda. No bad as people complain anyway I've completed EOS vault mission and then I visited EVA got jaal on my team. Took out most of the kett outposts and solved all the Remnant puzzles and located the vault, rescued Moshae and destroyed the Kett temple, but while entering the vault in voeld as soon as I enter through the door Ryder's Life support depletes rapidly. So how can I upgrade Ryder's life support so that I can fix the vault on voeld or do I have to complete any specific mission first?

Answer (score 4):

The vault on Voeld is surrounded on all sides by a small moat of ferrofluid. Simply jump over the moat and you should be fine. If not, simply dash inside. As soon as you activate the Gravity Well your life support should go back to normal.

From there, activate the vault's auxiliary power. After a second, SAM should tell you Life Support is back online and you won't be freezing inside the vault anymore.

Comment: once I've activated the gravity well and got the first door open inside my life support quickly depletes now outside but inside of the vault

Comment: @mayurmanudhanya Did you "activate the vault's auxiliary power"?

Comment: How can I do that @dcshannon?

Comment: @mayurmanudhanya I don't remember having any issues with this vault, myself. I believe that activating the first console (or pedestal or whatever they're called) activates the vault's auxiliary power.